# Problems with convergence in mean

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series

I hope you can help me with the following problem

Let $\{ e_i : i\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ be and independent U.I. sequence of scalar random variables with zero mean. Let $\{ A_j : j \geq 0\}$ be a sequence of real scalars such that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\vert A_j \vert < \infty$. Show that, $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$$
converges in first  mean to 0, where $Y_i=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}A_je_{i-j}$

any suggestion is welcome